# Grails 3: Custom taglib not recognized

Tags: taglib, grails-3.0

Using Grails 3.0.9

I tried setting up a custom tag, but I can't get it to work. I created the following groovy file in grails-app/taglib: **BeanFormGenerator.groovy**

```
class BeanFormGenerator {    
    def renderList = { attrs, body ->
        // reads the 'values' attribute from the attributes list
        def list = attrs.values
        // iterates and renders list values
        list.each {
            // uses the implicit 'out' variable to append content to the response
            out << "<span class=\"element\"> ${it} </span>"
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this call in a gsp file:

```
<g:renderList values="[1, 2, 3]">check check</g:renderList>
```

I get the error:

> Tag [renderList] does not exist. No tag library found for namespace: g

I tried creating a custom namespace inside of BeanFormGenerator:

```
static namespace = "beanform"
```

But this just caused  to be treated as markup. What am I doing wrong? The documentation makes it seem like this should be all there is to it. I'm running this inside of IntelliJ community edition if that makes a difference.

Comment: *Quite simply, to create a tag library create a Groovy class that ends with the convention TagLib and place it within the grails-app/taglib directory* http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.9/guide/single.html#taglibs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quite simply, to create a tag library create a **Groovy class that ends
>   with the convention TagLib** and place it within the grails-app/taglib
>   directory

[grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.9/guide/single.html#taglibs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.9/guide/single.html#taglibs)